# How to change page title dynamically in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am having some mad problems with Meteor and Meteor Router, specifically the `ready` callback of Meteor subscription handles and their interplay with the Router. if I call the subscription by ID it works perfectly, if I call it by 'slug' it doesnt work.

I have two publications on the server:

```
Meteor.publish('singleChannel', function(id) {
    return id && Channels.find(id);
});

Meteor.publish('singleChannelSlug', function(_slug) {
    return Channels.find({slug:_slug});
});
```

In `client/main.js` I have two subscriptions for the publications:

```
singleChannelSlugHandle = Meteor.subscribe('singleChannelSlug', Session.get('currentChannelSlug'), function () {
    console.log('singleChannelSlug is ready() ');
});

singleChannelIdHandle = Meteor.subscribe('singleChannel', Session.get('currentChannelId'),function () {
    console.log('singleChannelIdHandle ready');
});
```

in the router I have:

```
Meteor.Router.add({

'/channel/:slug': {
    as:'channelPage',
    to: function () {
        console.log('route1');
        if (singleChannelSlugHandle.ready()) {
            console.log( 'ready();', Channels.findOne({slug:Session.get('currentChannelSlug')}) );
            Session.set('currentChannelId', Channels.findOne({slug:Session.get('currentChannelSlug')})._id );
            return 'channelPage';
        } else {
            return 'spinner';
        };
    },
    and: function(slug) {
        Session.set('currentChannelSlug', slug);
    }
}
```

});

this is the console.log() output:

```
route1
singleChannelIdHandle ready 
singleChannelSlug is ready()
```

now what should happen is that as soon as the `singleChannelSlugHandle` becomes ready, it fetches the _id and writes it into the Session and navigates to the page. But for whatever reason it never works. console.log('ready();') never gets called.

Oddly it works once if I change a file and save. If I rewrite the route using just ID it works too, but I need it to get to work with the slug as I need prettier urls than some abstract ID. I been on this for 4-5 hours now and can't figure it out

Comment: This is a old router and it's not support anymore, try to use IronRouter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think the callback for `to` is reactive, so despite the sub's `ready()` method being reactive, the `to` callback won't re-run.

Second, always return a cursor in your publish:

```
Meteor.publish('singleChannel', function(id) {
    return /*id &&*/ Channels.find(id);
});
```

And lastly, use Iron Router -- it's exactly what you're after (see `waitOn`)

Comment: thanks. sorry thought I solved the problem, but came back to this and saw your answer.